# Stop GUI Thread from freezing

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have a C# (.NET 4), GUI (WPF) program that uses BackgroundWorker (that calls a "Parallel.For" in it)

and i noticed that the GUI thread is  always freezing so that the cores can work on the other threads.

The GUI Thread has no tasks to perform so that's not the reason I'm experiencing slow GUI.

Thank you

Comment: It depends: How much work are the background worker threads pumping back to the UI (modifying collections etc.)?

Comment: thanks for the quick respond, the background worker thread is not pumping much work back to the UI, maybe once in 2 seconds...
And when (as a test) I comment the "NotifyProgressChanged", it is still slow

Comment: Show us the code so we can help.

Comment: I would be surprised if the background worker block the UI. We run a lot of background processing (although we are not using BackgroundWorker) and the only reason I ever had UI freeze up on me was when doing lots of work on the UI thread itself.

Comment: Besides from the UI and the backgroundWorker threads, there are a lot (lot!) of other threads created by the Parallel.For method.
The UI Thread actually does nothing

Comment: Is there any way that I can assign a core for the UI ?

Comment: that won't help if you are running tasks in the main thread or blocking which is what this sounds like.

Comment: You will have to post the code that "uses BackgroundWorker" and "calls a Parallel.For".

Answer (score 0):

If the UI thread is executing the Parallel.For it will block until all parallel thread have finished their work!